# How to create a patcher for a C# dll

Tags: c#, patch

I'm looking for a method for making a distributable patch of a C# dll file. While I was able to find stuff like dnSpy, which allow to open and edit DLLs, but what I'm looking for is a way to distribute my edits to other people without distributing the whole modified DLL. Is there any tools which allow for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the droid you're looking for:

https://github.com/0xd4d/dnlib

you can do all kind of edits directly in your C# patcher executable, eg:

```
// Load the original assembly
ModuleDefMD module = ModuleDefMD.Load(originalExe);

//Iterate through all types to find the class inheriting from MyClass
TypeDef targetClass = FindClassInheritingFrom(module, "MyClass");

//edit the constructor
var ctor = targetClass.Methods.First(x => x.IsConstructor);
//replace some line with nop
ctor.Body.Instructions[5] = OpCodes.Nop.ToInstruction();
ctor.Body.UpdateInstructionOffsets();

// Save the modified assembly with a different name
module.Write(newName);
```